# Como puedo reemplazar multiples string para obtener el porcentaje

Tags: python

intento crear un bot market para telegram. El problema es que sin la variable str no puedo obtener los precios de cierre (de hoy y ayer), por lo tanto, tampoco puedo obtener el porcentaje.

```
def ticker_command(update, context):
Close = pdr.get_data_yahoo(empresas,    start=inicio,   end=fin)
CloseX = str(Close["Close"][0]. round(2))
CloseY = pdr.get_data_yahoo(empresas,    start=ayer, end= ayer)
CloseYx = str(CloseY["Close"][0]. round(2))
PercentChange = "{:.2%}" .format((CloseX*100)/CloseYx)
```

Hay alguna manera de sacar el PercentChange sin la necesidad de desvincular el string? . Caso contrario, que otra manera creativa podría realizar para desvincular este error. Gracias

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.float64") to str

Comment: no lo conviertas a string

Comment: Si le saco la variable str no puedo obtener los precios en ambas fechas.

Comment: por que?, no veo que estes utilizando esas variable en otro lugar

Comment: Tenes razón, el problema no son los str al principio de las variables de Close... El problema es la llamada del bot hacia telegram en donde pido varia información, voy a pensar y solucionar esto último.

Comment: de igual forma puedes hacer `(int(CloseX)*100)/int(CloseYx)`

Comment: Se agradece de más tu ayuda complementaria Christian, que tengas un buen día. Saludos